# AngularJS Select - Automatically select option

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, font-awesome

Afternoon all, i've got a select box that i have created in Angular that contains a FontAwesome icon instead of text. You can see here that i've had to use **ng-bind-html** to get this to display a unicode value, but what now does not work is as the select box is open, it no longer 'auto selects' the current value.

The Select Box

```
<select ng-model="item.IconCssClass" class="fontawesomeselect">
    <option ng-repeat="i in Icons" value="{{i.icon}}" ng-bind-html="i.unicode|html">    </option>
</select>
```

My CSS:

```
.fontawesomeselect {
    font-family: FontAwesome, Lato;
    width: 40px;
}
```

In the directive (more or less):

```
scope.Icons = [
        { icon: 'fa-phone', unicode: '&#xf095;' },
        { icon: 'fa-gbp', unicode: '&#xf154;' }];

scope.item = { "IconCssClass": "fa-phone" };
```

The select option is not automatically selected at all, any ideas if i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks like `fa-lock` doesn't exist in your `scope.Icons` array. Try adding it there or change the selected icon to `fa-phone` or `fa-gbp`.

Comment: OK my bad i chose the wrong item to demo, will change now. The item is definitely there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to use the [ng-selected directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) to load with the correct icon selected.

```
<option ng-selected="i.icon === item.IconCssClass" ng-repeat="i in Icons" value="{{i.icon}}" ng-bind-html="i.unicode|html"></option>
```

Comment: I knew it would be simple! Cheers will try when I get home :)